# json_query not returning expected results in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible playbook with a task where I try to query a JSON object.

The JSON is like:

```json
  { 
     "data": { 
        [ 
           { 
             "name": "myname", 
             "id": 1 
           }, 
           { 
             "name": "myname2", 
             "id": 2 
           }, 
           { 
             "name": "myname3", 
             "id": 3 
           }, 
         ] 
      } 
 }
```

The JSON is stored in a variable called `test_json`.

My task looks like:

```yaml
-  name:
   debug:
      msg: "{{ test_json | to_json | json_query('data[?name==''myname3'']')
```

The debug message line is empty. I would expect to print out the element where `name == myname3`.

Comment: You probably don't need the `to_json`, and you should use backticks in your JMESPath query: ```"{{ test_json | json_query('data[?name==`myname3`]') }}"```, as pointed In the documentation's notes: _"[quoting literals using backticks avoids escaping quotes and maintains readability](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_selecting_json_data.html#codecell4)"_

Comment: This said, the JSON you are providing here is not valid, you can always lint it, e.g. with online tools like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com. So that might also be part of your issue.

Comment: You *absolutely* don't need `to_json`, because `to_json` produces a string and `json_query` requires a data structure (like a dictionary or a list) as input.

Answer (score 0):

For a valid JSON structure a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    VALID_JSON: {
      "data": [
           {
             "name": "myname1",
             "id": 1
           },
           {
             "name": "myname2",
             "id": 2
           },
           {
             "name": "myname3",
             "id": 3
           }
         ]
       }

  tasks:

  - debug:
      var: VALID_JSON | json_query('data[?name==`myname3`]')

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ VALID_JSON | json_query('data[?name==`myname3`]') }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ***************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  VALID_JSON | json_query('data[?name==`myname3`]'):
  - id: 3
    name: myname3

TASK [debug] ***************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - id: 3
    name: myname3
```